# Can't delete folder named drkit

Tags: macos, finder, time-machine, permission, trash

I recently restored my Mac from a backup and it left behind some files in a deleted users folder. I deleted all of them but there is one folder, titled `drkit`, that I can't seem to delete:

[image: Screenshot of directory]

though it shows before I delete it

[image: Screenshot of error]

It disappears afterward and gives this error code but then comes back after navigating to a different folder and then back.

I have run First Aid on the SSD with no errors.

I also can't seem to `rm` it with terminal as it runs without errors but doesn't seem to actually delete it because drkit still shows up in an `ls`. `sudo rm` changes nothing.  Also when I "Get Info", it says "unknown permissions".

When I run `ls -al` I get:

```
basilnelson@Basils-mbp problemParent % ls -al
ls: drkit: Operation not permitted
total 0
drwx------@ 3 basilnelson  staff  96 Jun 30 22:20 .
drwx------  3 basilnelson  staff  96 Jul  3 09:09 ..
ls: fts_read: Operation not permitted
```

and if I use sudo ls -al I get the same thing

`pwd` shows:

```
basilnelson@Basils-mbp problemParent % pwd
/Users/basilnelson/.funny/Library/Containers/developer.apple.wwdc-Release/Data/problemParent
```

I moved it to a hidden folder in my user directory because It made the trash difficult to use as it would error every time.

Comment: What is the parent folder? Type `pwd` and post.  By the way,, the command for `rm` is `rm -rf foo/bar`. The flags come first, not last

Comment: What is that in your `Library` folder?  What did you (attempt to) install there?

Comment: this isn't a result of installing something, this used to be in the deleted users folder, and the folder that is now .funny was called basilnelson. when I tried to delete that folder and its contents, it seemed to get hung up on the drkit folder and left it behind.

Comment: Do you need what in `.funny`?  Can you try deleting that?

Comment: there is nothing but drkit in .funny. Also I have tried deleting it from there and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem (although I was the problem user, not someone else).  In order to be able to operate at all on `drkit`, I had to reboot into Repair Mode. Possibly important note: all this was on an M1 Mac Mini, so that reboot meant "hold-down-power-until-you-reboot-into-Repair-Mode."

Once I was in Repair Mode, I could run Terminal, navigate to `/Volumes/Macintosh HD - Data/Users/scott/Library/Containers/developer.apple.wwdc-Release/Data/Library`, and there revealed was `drkit`.  `xattr` showed it to have three extended attributes:

```
com.apple.macl
com.apple.quarantine
com.apple.rootless
```

`xattr -c drkit` removed all those.

`ls -alr drkit` showed it to contain only a single SQLite db, `coreidvd.sqlitedb`, and `xattr` in turn showed that db to have two extended attributes:

```
com.apple.metadata:com_apple_backup_excludeItem
com.apple.quarantine
```

Both had dates of Apr 18 of this year (2023).

All that appears to be left over from looking at WWDC stuff.  Somewhat tacky of WWDC stuff to have left nearly immortal gnomes in the file system, but with macOS not running interference for it, removing the container with
`rm -rf developer.apple.wwdc-Release`
worked.

Comment: I did exactly what you did, and it worked! thanks!